# HashSet turning into TreeSet when unit testing JDO GAE/J app in maven

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, junit, jdo

I have a Java app for GAE which uses maven (the net.kindleit version) with the following classes:

```
public class C1 {

    ...
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "c1")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    private Set<C2> c2s = new HashSet<C2>();

    public Set<C2> getC2s() {
        return this.c2s;
    }
    '''
}

public class C2 {

    private C1 c1;

    ...
    more properties, getters and setters
    ...

}
```

In one of my tests, I am executing the following:

```
C2 myC2 = new C2(myC1);
myC1.getC2s().add(myC2);
```

The unit test works running inside Eclipse, and the code also works in the production app, but when I run the unit tests under maven, the test fails with the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    com.me.model.C2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at com.me.service.C2ServiceImpl.createC2(C2ServiceImpl.java:319)
```

I understand the exception, as C2 does not implement comparable, and that would be required to insert things into a TreeSet, but the question is, why is it returning a Set backed by TreeSet, and not by HashSet.